# React - Remove item from array using its name / value

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a `JSONArrary` like this:

```
myJsonArray = [
    {
        id: '1A',
        name: 'GER'
    },
    {
        id: '2B',
        name: 'BRU',
    },
    {
        id: '3C',
        name: 'ARG'
    }
]
```

I tried to many ways to remove a complete item. At the moment to remove it, the only value I have is `id`.

How I can remove (for example) the item with `id: '1A'` and get as result an array like this:

```
myJsonArray = [
    {
        id: '2B',
        name: 'BRU',
    },
    {
        id: '3C',
        name: 'ARG'
    }
]
```

Comment: hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter method to remove the item from array.

```
myJsonArray = myJsonArray.filter(x => x.id !== '1A');
```

Comment: Simple and elegant answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be:

```
let index = -1;
for( let i = 0; i < myJsonArray.length; i++ ){
    if( myJsonArray[i].id === searchId ){
       index = i;
    }
}
if(index == -1){
   //however you want to handle it
   console.log("not found");
}
myJsonArray.splice(index, 1);
```